# How to sort by a calculated column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, sorting

We have a number of fields in our `offers` table that determine an offer's price, however one crucial component for the price is an exchange rate fetched from an external API. We still need to sort offers by actual current price.

For example, let's say we have two columns in the `offers` table: `exchange` and `premium_percentage`. The `exchange` is the name of the source for the exchange rate to which an external request will be made. `premium_percentage` is set by the user. In this situation, it is impossible to sort offers by current price without knowing the exchange rate, and that maybe different depending on what's in the `exchange` column.

How would one go about this? Is there a way to make Postgres calculate current price and then sort offers by it?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 13):

```
SELECT
    product_id,
    get_current_price(exchange) * (premium_percentage::float/100 + 1) AS price
FROM offers
ORDER BY 2;
```

Note the `ORDER BY 2` to sort by the second ordinal column.

You can instead repeat the expression you want to sort by in the `ORDER BY` clause. But that can result in multiple evaluation.

Or you can wrap it all in a subquery so you can name the output columns and refer to them in other clauses.

```
SELECT product_id, price
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        product_id,
        get_current_price(exchange) * (premium_percentage::float/100 + 1)
    FROM offers
) product_prices(product_id, price)
ORDER BY price;
```

Comment: In the ORDER BY clause you can use output column names, so it can also be `ORDER BY price` in the first query.

Comment: @klin Did you try it? You actually can't, because `price` isn't a column of any table, it's an alias for a calculated column in the `select` result-list. Some databases do allow you to do it anyway, but it's not SQL-standard, and PostgreSQL isn't one of the ones that permits it.

Comment: From [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html) *An output column's name can be used to refer to the column's value in ORDER BY and GROUP BY clauses...* [SqlFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6efb2/1)

Comment: What about performance in this case, especially talking about big data set?

Comment: @viktor.svirskyy It'll generally be awful, because PostgreSQL will have no way to avoid executing the sort expression on every row in order to determine which rows are of interest for subsequent limits, filters, etc. You should consider a *functional index* on the expression.